# SSDT How to deal with LinkedServer variable within SQL scripts

Tags: testing, sql-server-data-tools, linked-server

I am using **SQL Server Database Project** inside Visual Studio.
I have three databases. Database **P** (production), Database **T** (test) and a database **D** which **P** and **T** has a dependency on.
Database **P** and **D** are in the same server/instance (production server). Database **T** is on a different server (test server) and there is linked server which points to the production server.

The database **D** is setup as a variable in publish profile.

The **D** tables are registered as synonyms and SQL script use these synonyms.

When I deploy into production it works.

How can I setup, that when I am publishing into test environment, I would like to use the LinkedServer? (In production it is not needed, but in the test I need it)

I can use something like this

```
CREATE SYNONYM [foo].[Bar]
FOR [$(LinkedServerToDatabase_D)].[$(D)].[foo].[Bar]
```

And I am able to deploy to production and also test, but this solution has a downside. In this case I have to put `@@servername` result into the publish profile variable. If database will migrate to different server I will have to redeploy the database.

Is it possible to deploy this to production

```
CREATE SYNONYM [foo].[Bar]
    FOR [$(D)].[foo].[Bar]
```

and this to test?

```
 CREATE SYNONYM [foo].[Bar]
    FOR [$(LinkedServerToDatabase_D)].[$(D)].[foo].[Bar]
```

So I don't need to worry about production server name?

Comment: do not use `@@servername` create all synonyms by using 4 part name. In case this database located on the same instance just use exact server name for the variable or you can use `localhost` or `local`. Do not recall exact value

Comment: Hello @DmitrijKultasev I am trying to run something like `select * from [local or localhost].DatabaseName.SchemaName.TableName` but I am getting an error `Could not find server 'localhost' in sys.servers. Verify that the correct server name was specified.`

Comment: I don't recall, but you can definitely specify exact instance name and it will work. You can do that for every environment in the publish profiles. In case that would be linked server, then specify linked server

Comment: IMO you should redesign testing environment to avoid "sometimes it's on different server, sometimes not" problem. But event without these thoughts I don't really understand where the problem stands. If P and T are separate projects then there is no intersection in synonym definition - those are two independend synonyms in different databases.

Comment: Ivan, it's not "sometimes it's on different server, sometimes not" problem. The test environment and production are clearly defined. Just part of the production system (read-only) has to be accessible from the test to minimize the complexity. Not sure, but I think I overcame the issue with a database dependency (dacpac) in the ssdt project pointing to the different server. For the future, I think the diagram is better for explanation.